# Java Spring Hibernate Hash Password

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hash

I got one method in spring that has to return user with a hashed password. I got same method in two different projects. In first one works correctly, in second return the real password, so User cannot authenticate because pass from login form is md5 hashed and the one that come from db is not. When I debug first project after method return user it process to correct class that call it. In second - when return user it goes to AopUtils.java. Where can be the difference:

```
public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
    User usr = new User();
    String hql = "FROM com.webstore.entity.User U WHERE U.username = :username";
    Query query = sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("username", username);
    if (query.list().isEmpty()) return usr;
    else if (query.list().size() == 1) {
        usr = (User)query.list().get(0);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + usr.getPassword());
        return usr;
    }
    return usr;
```

Comment: Your code does not show anything relevant to your problem. Are you sure the value for the password in the db is encrypted? Your method as you show, simply return the value it fetches from the DB.

Comment: You're providing to little information here, so I'm not sure what the question is. If the password is stored in plaintext in the database, just run it through the same algorithm that the hashed password runs through and compare the results. I would still strongly recommend that you hash the password in the database as well. Regarding the method returning to AopUtils, I would guess that it might be related to some @Transactional annotation or similar - some sort of proxying. Just step out of the debugger until you get back to the calling class.